# How many users earned a tag badge before me?

Tags: support, tags, tag-badges, data-explorer

I just earned the bronze [youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api) badge (yay).  Looking at the [tag badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2612/youtube-api), I see that it has been awarded 8 times, with me being the 8th.

Back in December I earned the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) bronze badge.  By looking at the specific [badge tag page for my user ID](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4076/swift?userid=2415822) I can see that I earned it and when I earned it, but I don't see how many users earned it before me, or after me.

Is there somewhere I can see who earned a tag badge before me?  Maybe a SEDE query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4076/swift

Comment: @PetahChristian that shows me how many people earned the badge in total, not necessarily before or after me.  Do I have to manually count down the list to figure out where I rank among everyone else with the badge?

Comment: Same format as the other badge. The only difference is that no one else has more recently earned the [tag:youtube-api] badge.  So, yes, you'd (eventually) have to count in both cases.

Comment: @PetahChristian I understand that.  Basically I'm looking for a query or some other way to see that information without manually counting down the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/436491/bronze-swift-badge-ranking), you're number #181 for the bronze Swift badge.

```
-- This query retrieves all the bronze swift badge users and ranks them according to their badge date received.

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b.Date ASC), b.UserId, b.Date DateReceived, u.DisplayName
FROM Users u, Badges b
WHERE b.name='swift' and b.class=3
and u.Id=b.UserId
GROUP BY b.Date, b.UserId, u.DisplayName
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs a generic query (parameterized by badge and user), I've created one here:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/446048/order-of-user-being-awarded-badge

JAL appears as #180 (presumably another user was deleted since PetahChristian's answer):

- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/446048/order-of-user-being-awarded-badge?BadgeName=swift&BadgeClass=3&UserId=2415822